# SwiftUI - OnExitCommand inside TabView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, tvos

I have lately been trying to make a tvOS app, but have run into the following rather annoying problem. I can't use navigation inside a TabView and still have the menu button on the remove take me back to the previous state.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var selection : Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
            ExpView()
            .tabItem {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Explore")
                }
            }
            .tag(0)
        }
    }
}

struct ExpView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "Hey")) {
                Text("Detail")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var title : String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there any way to enable the menu button to go back to the previous view in the hierachy without dismissing the app completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a workaround for the issue.
If you place the navigationView outside the TabView and then use the following code it works:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var selection : Int = 0
    @State var hideNavigationBar : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
                ExpView(hideNavigationBar: self.$hideNavigationBar)
                .tabItem {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        Text("Explore")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExpView: View {
    
    @Binding var hideNavigationBar : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "Hey")) {
            Text("Detail")
        }.navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(self.hideNavigationBar)
        .onAppear {
            self.hideNavigationBar = true
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var title : String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call dismiss on Menu it is called automatically for NavigationLink (so calling one more dismiss quits to main menu)

Here are fixed views. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
struct ExploreView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "Hey")) {
                Text("Detail")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    var title : String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot the NavigationView in my example.. and I have tried to with your code but it still doesn't seem to work. Also this is being tested on a simulator, not sure if this makes any difference?

Comment: Your code works, but not if it is inside a TabView.